# Validation of Input Field Against its Valuehelp Items

Tags: sapui5

I'd like to validate user inputs against its ValueHelp items

I'd rather not set the Input field to `valueHelpOnly` as that disables typing for the user.

Let's say we have a value-help list of "Rabbit", "Steed", and "Goat".
I want the user to be able to type it out, but if they forget to type it fully like typing *"Rab"* instead of "Rabbit", I want the input field to match the input against the value-help items list, and throw an invalid entry error message.

What's the way of validating the user input against the value-help items list? Is there a way to validate this using regex?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `sap.m.ComboBox` which I recommend over `sap.m.Input`: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.ComboBox/sample/sap.m.sample.ComboBoxValidation

E.g. with "Rabbit", "Steed", and "Goat":
[image: sapui5 combobox marking incomplete entry as invalid]

But if you want to stick with `sap.m.Input`, the same can be achieved by evaluating `selectedKey` and the `value`. If none of the keys are matched and the value is **not** an empty string, then the value is not from the value-help list. In that case, set the `valueState` of the input control to `Error`.

Here is a small demo:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
], Fragment => Fragment.load({
  definition: `<Input xmlns="sap.m"
    showSuggestion="true"
    placeholder="Type rabbit, steed, or goat"
    change=".onChange">
    <SuggestionItem key="1" text="Rabbit" />
    <SuggestionItem key="2" text="Steed" />
    <SuggestionItem key="3" text="Goat" />
  </Input>`,
  controller: {
    onChange: function(event) {
      const input = event.getSource();
      const isInvalid = !input.getSelectedKey() && input.getValue().trim();
      input.setValueState(isInvalid ? "Error" : "None");
    },
  },
}).then(control => control.placeAt("content"))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

Comment: Ah, yes. The ComboBox would be a good option, it's just that my manager believes that ValueHelp is more suitable when there is a long list of options to choose from given that ValueHelps pop up a dialog that can display more items.

Comment: I've implemented it but it always runs into error state even when selecting from the valueHelp.
`   onLiveValidate:function(oEvent){
   var oInput= oEvent.getSource();
   var bValid= !oInput.getSelectedKey() && oInput.getValue().trim();
   oInput.setValueState(bValid ? "Error":"None");
  },`

What I'd like bValid to do is compare getValue() to the list of items in valueHelp, not see if user selected a key. I want the user to be able to type the value & get it validated as error or not if the typed value doesnt match a value help item.